# android:layout_centerInParent does not work

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I have an image that I want to place in the center of the screen. Despite of my expectations, it is centered horizontally but not vertically. That is, the image touches the screen top.

The same layout shows ok in a sandbox project, but unfortunately not in the real one.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <!-- ... -->
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/progress2"
                android:src="@drawable/wait2"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

The lines

```
               android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
               android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

are of course unnecessary, but the thing does not work in either case.

Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT: it looks like it's relevant that the view is shown from an `InputMethodService`.

Comment: "The same layout shows ok in a sandbox project, but unfortunately not in the real one." What are the changes? You might want to show the entire layout code and not just a part.

Comment: Why is your layout so complicated?  What's the purpose of all the nested layouts?

Comment: @David: Thx for the idea. I copied the whole layout into the sandbox project: it works there. But not in the real one. So I'm still puzzled.

Comment: @Aleks G: it was simpler before I began attempts to isolate the misfeature. I need some views to overlap,

Comment: @18446744073709551615 wouldn't that prove that the layout is alright, your real project is changing something and you are not showing that part. So we can only guess, that's just time consuming for everyone.

Comment: @David: why, your comments have been much more useful than "just time consuming". In fact, the sandbox is an Activity and the real project is an InputMethodService. Maybe _that_ is the cause.

Answer (score 6):

I just had the same Problem. I used

```
android:layout_centerInParent
```

and it worked on the AndroidStudio preview and on an Nexus 4 with 4.3 device. But on Galaxy S1 with 2.3 it did not work.

I fixed it by wrapping the Layout i wanted to center in an RelativeLayout and center that with the gravity attribute:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

<RelativeLayout
    ...
```

That worked on both devices.

Comment: This is fine if you only have element in the layout, but if you have elements aligned to the left and right of the layout then it will center those as well ignoring attributes like `layout_alignParentLeft="true"`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime this error comes in Constraint Layout
Use in RelativeLayout:

"android:layout_centerInParent="true">

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap it inside RelativeLayout element:

##### Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/RecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```